# Find the cluster CIDR for service IP allocations in Kubernetes

Tags: networking, service, kubernetes

How can I find what IP block is used by the api-service (or whatever other component is responsible) to dole out the service IPs, from a live cluster?

We use a self managed Kubernetes cluster deployed on AWS using Terraform. The networking is managed by Calico. However from what I have read it seems like Calico is only responsible for the pod and container IPs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can run below command, and in the output you will find your cluster ip range like `--service-cluster-ip-range=x.x.x.x/x`

```
kubectl cluster-info dump  | grep --color service-cluster-ip-range
```

Comment: Is it possible to change the service IP range of an already initialized kube cluster?

Answer (score 0):

This is a variable passed to your kube-apiserver at initial runtime, for example:

`--service-cluster-ip-range=10.3.0.0/20`